# Correctly opening sharepoint urls to document library items

Tags: sharepoint, url, documents

When I add a link to a document library word document from a publishing page and then click the link, I get prompted with a dialog enabling me to Open, Save or Cancel.

Can I prevent this prompt and open the document directly in word?

All the best

Answer (score 1):

This is natural browser behaviour and is in place to protect the user from accidentally opening possibly infected documents. On a machine my machine basis there is a setting that allows IE to open word documents within IE "in the same window"

- Open explorer
- Select the "tools >> folder options" menu item
- Select "file types" tab in the "file options" window
- Click advanced for the "Microsoft Word Document" registered file type
- Check the "Brows in Same Window"

If you are in a corporate network you can push this change out using group policy.